# When will I use a Class Variable in Java v.s an Instance Variable?

Tags: java, oop, instance-variables, class-variables

Here is a generic class that I have defined, what I would like to know is when I am creating more specific classes for instance a CAR class when would I use a Class Variable? My personal understanding of a class variable is that a single copy of a class variable that has been declared in a class will be declared using the keyword static, and that each object that has been instantiated from the class will contain a single copy of the class variable.

An instance variable allows each instance of a class / object that has been created from the class to have a separate copy of the instance variable per object?

So an instance variable is useful for defining the properties of a class / data-type e.g a House would have a location, but now when would I use a class variable in a House object? or in other words what is the correct use of a class object in designing a class?

```
public class InstanceVaribale {
public int id; //Instance Variable: each object of this class will have a seperate copy of this variable that will exist during the life cycle of the object.
static int count = 0; //Class Variable: each object of this class will contain a single copy of this variable which has the same value unless mutated during the lifecycle of the objects.

InstanceVaribale() {
    count++;

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    InstanceVaribale A = new InstanceVaribale();
    System.out.println(A.count);
    InstanceVaribale B = new InstanceVaribale();
    System.out.println(B.count);
    System.out.println(A.id);
    System.out.println(A.count);
    System.out.println(B.id);
    System.out.println(B.count);    
    InstanceVaribale C = new InstanceVaribale();
    System.out.println(C.count);
}
}
```

Comment: Avoid them when you can. Programs are easier to maintain without static variables, they are basically globals with some sugar coating

Comment: They're really called "static fields," not "class variables."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My personal understanding of a class variable is that a single copy of a class variable that has been declared in a class will be declared using the keyword static, and that each object that has been instantiated from the class will contain a single copy of the class variable.

No. It's not that "each object will contain a single copy". A static variable is associated with the *type* rather than each instance of the type. The *instances* don't have the variable at all.

There's exactly one variable (assuming you're only loading it from one classloader) *however* many instances of the type there are. No instances? Still one variable. A million instances? Still one variable.

Static variables are mostly useful for constants or constant-alikes - things like loggers, or "the set of valid prices" etc. Things which don't change over the course of the application. They should almost always be `final` in my experience, and the type should be an immutable type (like `String`). Where possible, use immutable collections too for static variables - or make sure the variable is private and that you never mutate the collection within the class.

You should *avoid* using static variables to store global changing state. It makes code much harder to test and reason about.

Comment: From what I understand now is that there is only one static variable and it is associated with the class and an instance of the variable does not contain the static variable but the class / type that the object has been instantiated from contains the variable and since the variable is contained with in the class there is only one variable which is independent of the instances, and the state of the static variable still exists even if there are zero instances of the class? Is it correct to say that the scope of a static variable is the class it's self and any code blocks with in can access it?

Comment: @Aaron: An instance of the *class* does not contain the static variable. The class itself *effectively* contains the static variable, yes. I wouldn't use the word "scope" here - it's pretty much orthogonal to talking about how many "copies" of a variable are present.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Every `object of the class` will have its **own copy of Instance Variable**,its `One per Object.`

**2.** But `static variable` will be **shared by all the objects of the class**, its `One per Class.`

**3.** Now i will give 2 example where these two will have importance.

**Instance variable:**

Consider a Gaming Program, then each player will have **different Name, Scores, Weapons-power, Stage reached, etc.....**

**Static variable:**

Consider a Banking program, where each client will be given **an Id, which is greater and unique than the previous one**, so static variable will be apt for this.

Answer (score 2):

Static variables are used to store values that are shared between all instances of the class.

If this is not the case, it should be an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

**Definitions:**

**Class variables:** Class variables also known as static variables are declared with the static keyword in a class, but outside a method, constructor, or block. `There would only be one copy of each class variable per class, regardless of how many objects are created from it`.

**Instance variables:** Instance variables are declared in a class, but outside a method. `When space is allocated for an object in the heap, a slot for each instance variable value is created`.

**Local variables:** Local variables are declared in methods, constructors, or blocks. `Local variables are created when the method, constructor, or block is entered and the variable will be destroyed once it exits the method, constructor, or block`.

**Examples:**

**Class variable:**

```
class ClassVar {
  static int count; //class level variable
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ClassVar obj1 = new ClassVar();
    ClassVar obj2 = new ClassVar();
    obj1.count=5;
    obj2.count=5;
    
    obj1.count++; //change in object1's count

    System.out.println(obj1.count); // 6
    System.out.println(obj2.count); // 6
  }
}
```

**Instance variable:**

```
class InstanceVar {
  int count; //instance level variable
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    InstanceVar obj1 = new InstanceVar();
    InstanceVar obj2 = new InstanceVar();
    obj1.count=5;
    obj2.count=5;
    
    obj1.count++; //change in object1's count

    System.out.println(obj1.count); // 6
    System.out.println(obj2.count); // 5
  }
}
```

As you may have noticed, the same code with the word `static` changes the implementation. `Updating object1’s count changes object2’s count as well`.

**A combined example**

```
public class Car {
    // Class variable
    static int numCars = 0;
    
    // Instance variables
    String make;
    String model;
    int year;
    
    public Car(String make, String model, int year) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
        
        // Increment the number of cars each time a new Car object is created
        numCars++;
    }
    
    public void printCarInfo() {
        System.out.println("Make: " + make + " ,Model: " + model + " ,Year: " + year);
    }
    
    public static void printNumCars() {
        System.out.println("Number of cars: " + numCars);
    }
}
```

In this example, `numCars` is a class variable because it's declared with the `static` keyword, meaning it's shared by all instances of the class. We use it to keep track of the total number of Car objects that have been created. This will be incremented every time a new instance of the Car class is created.

`make`, `model`, and `year` are instance variables because they're not declared as `static`, meaning they belong to each individual Car object. These will hold details of a particular car instance.

Now if we add a main method to demonstrate

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car car1 = new Car("Toyota", "Camry", 2021);
    Car car2 = new Car("Honda", "Civic", 2022);
    Car car3 = new Car("Ford", "Mustang", 2023);

    car1.printCarInfo();
    car2.printCarInfo();
    car3.printCarInfo();

    Car.printNumCars();
}
```

Here we have created three Car instances and printed their details. Now the value of the numCars will also be 3, as this is a class var and will be shared with all the instances of the Car class. The final output will look something like below.

```
Make: Toyota ,Model: Camry ,Year: 2021
Make: Honda ,Model: Civic ,Year: 2022
Make: Ford ,Model: Mustang ,Year: 2023
Number of cars: 3
```